# --dns flag equivalent for kubernetes yaml file?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dns, yaml

I want the pods that are created in my Kubernetes cluster to be able to use my preexisting custom DNS server.

The DNS is on a separate machine and, when running docker containers, I could set this using the `--dns` flag.

Is it possible to replicate that in Kubernetes pods?
I am also open to other suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: There are [settings on a Pod spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#hostname-and-name-resolution) for this or you can configure it at a cluster level.

Answer (score 0):

> or you can configure it at a cluster level

More precisely, as in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/superseb/f6894ddbf23af8e804ed3fe44dd48457), you can:

> Configure kube-dns to use an upstream nameserver instead of the one in `/etc/resolv.conf`:
>
> Save in `configmap.yml`:
>
> ```yaml
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: ConfigMap
> metadata:
>  name: kube-dns
>  namespace: kube-system
> data:
>  upstreamNameservers: |
>    ["8.8.8.8"]
> ```
>
> Then:
>
> ```
> kubectl create -f configmap.yml
> ```

Official documentation: "[CoreDNS configuration equivalent to kube-dn](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#coredns-configuration-equivalent-to-kube-dns)"

Also:

> Retrieve nameserver kube-dns is using:
>
> ```
> kubectl exec -ti -n kube-system \
>   $(kubectl get --no-headers=true pods -l k8s-app=kube-dns \
>             -o custom-columns=:metadata.name -n kube-system) \
>   -c kubedns -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
> ```